# PHP5 and MSSQL iterate array and return results for each

Tags: php, sql-server

Running from an Ubuntu system with PHP5/Apache, I'd like to key and populate an array used in a loop to retrieve the same two fields from many databases located on a single MSSQL server, then have them display the results in a HTML table.  Retrieval and display works below but it retrieves them all at once very slowly, then at the end, populates the HTML table with all of the data.  How can I better code this to retrieve each element from the array and display one at a time in HTML table format (or in batches) with a timeout of X seconds for each element?  I'm learning PHP on the fly with web searches plus trial and error so please forgive my crude coding skills.

```
<?php
print "<style> table, th, td { border: 1px solid gray; }</style>";
print "<table><tr><th>CUSTOMER</th><th>Database</th><th>DATE_RECEIVE</th><th>DATE_PROCESS</th></tr>";
$hostname = "sqlserver\instance";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
MSSQL_CONNECT($hostname,$username,$password) or DIE("DATABASE FAILED TO RESPOND.");
$DATABASES01 = array(
    "CUSTOMER01" => "CUST01-DB",
    "CUSTOMER02" => "CUST02-DB",
    "CUSTOMER03" => "CUST03-DB",
    "CUSTOMER04" => "CUST04-DB",
);

foreach ($DATABASES01 as $KEY => $DBNAME) {
    MSSQL_SELECT_DB($DBNAME) or DIE("Database unavailable");
    $QUERY = "SELECT date_receive, date_process FROM table WHERE criteria";
    $result = mssql_query( $QUERY );
    for ($i = 0; $i < mssql_num_rows( $result ); ++$i) {
        $line = mssql_fetch_row($result);
        print "<TR><TD>" . $KEY . "</TD><TD>" . $DBNAME . "</TD><TD>" . $line[0] . "</TD><TD>" . $line[1] . "</TD></TR>";
    }
}
print "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Why are you establishing connection in a loop??

Comment: Novice error as I'm trying to learn.  I guess that MSSQL_CONNECT entry should be outside the loop.  Thank you for pointing that out I've just moved it outside of and before the loop.

Comment: What is `criteria` ??? I think you need to do a quick SQL tutorial

Comment: @Akintunde _I'd like to key and populate an array used in a loop to retrieve the same two fields from **many databases** located on a **single MSSQL server**_

Comment: Dean: No if you are really trying to acces 4 databases, the select_db is fine where it is

Comment: Do you actually have a selection criteria to use in `WHERE criteria`

Comment: I tried to make the example code snippet brief.  There are over 50 databases that I need to query for the same two fields.  The WHERE 'criteria' was left out in an effort to simplify my question/answer/example and I didn't think it would be relevant as the statements work.  Let's just say WHERE status=new.